# Interview : update table values using select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-update

Interviewer asked me one question, which seems very easy, but I couldn't figure out, how to solve this

```
Name  | Gender
--------------
A     | F
B     | M
C     | F
D     | F
E     | M
```

From the above data, gender was wrongly entered, which means in place of `F` it should be `M` and in place of `M` it should `F`. How to update whole table with a single line sql query (don't use pl/sql block). Since, if I will update gender column one by one, then possible error would be all rows values of gender column becomes either `F` or `M`.

Final output should be

```
Name  | Gender
--------------
A     | M
B     | F
C     | M
D     | M
E     | F
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
Update TableName Set Gender=Case when Gender='M' Then 'F' Else 'M' end
```

On OP request..update using Select...

```
Update TableName T Set Gender=(
Select Gender from TableName B where  T.Gender!=B.Gender and rownum=1);
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91087/15)

Comment: yes... this was my answer too, but he says "It is ok, I need the solution using select statement" . Even I use `decode` function.

Comment: @jWeavers you can't `UPDATE` a table using a single `SELECT` execution. This is by design. Unless it's some sort of "trick" and he wants you to `SELECT` from a stored procedure which executes the `UPDATE`

Comment: @jWeavers create a stored proc which includes and `UPDATE` and execute a `SELECT` on it... but if that's what they're after it seems a bit silly to me.

Comment: @Matthew, actually you can- `update t set c1 = (select something from somewhere sw where sw.id = t.id)`, but in this case WHY ?? the `update` with the `case` is the right way (and not because *if I will update gender column one by one, then possible error would be all rows values of gender column becomes either F or M*, for this we have transactions)

Comment: @AmitSingh please check your query once more, there is some problem

Comment: @jWeavers i updated the command and provide link for sql fiddle demo try  it now

Comment: @AmitSingh why did you used `rownum=1` ?

Comment: @jWeavers, because the subquery must return only one row. Actually he could have used `select 'F' v from dual union all select 'M' from dual` instead of `tableName` and it would still work (without the rownum=1)

Comment: i use rownum =1 bcz it should return single value ...in update command to set value of column

Comment: @A.B.Cade that code still contains an `UPDATE` statement. My understanding is that OP doesn't want to use any `UPDATE` at all.

Comment: @Matthew, I don't think so... it doesn't make sense to update without an "update". Though you can use `merge` (even though it contains an update clause it's not an update command...)

Answer (score 3):

```
update table_name
set    gender =  case when gender = 'F' then 'M' 
                      when gender = 'M' then 'F'
                  end
```

SQL works on `Set theory` principles, so updates are happening in parallel, you don't 
    need Temporary storage to store the values before overwriting like we do in 
    other programming language while swapping two values.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do such an update is as [Amit singh first answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16330179/1083652).

But if you really want to have a `select statement` in your update (have know idea why), then you can do something like this:

```
update table1 t
set Gender = (select case when i.Gender = 'F' Then 'M' else 'F' end 
                from table1 i 
                where i.Name = t.Name);
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7e57/3)

Answer (score 0):

**sql server example but same applies**

declare @Table TABLE
(
    Id int,
    Value char(1)
)

insert into @Table

select 1, 'F'

union select 2, 'F'

union select 3, 'F'

union select 4, 'M'

union select 5, 'M'

union select 6, 'M'

select * from @Table

update @Table set Value = case when Value = 'F' then 'M' when Value = 'M' then 'F' else Value End

select * from @Table

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:-

```
update [table] a 
set Gender=(select case when gender='F' then 'M' else 'F' end from [table] b
where a.name=b.name)
```

above query will match the names and will update gender accordingly.